# Confusion with NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimezone

I am trying trying to get a create an object of NSDate this way

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   // [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day    = [weekdayComponents day];
    NSInteger month  = [weekdayComponents month];
    NSInteger year   = [weekdayComponents year];


    NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComps setDay:day];
    [timeZoneComps setMonth:month];
    [timeZoneComps setYear:year];
    [timeZoneComps setHour:00];
    [timeZoneComps setMinute:00];
    [timeZoneComps setSecond:01];

    m_currentDate         = [gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];
```

When I log the currentDate, I get this

```
"2014-07-07 06:00:01 +0000"
```

If  I save this to plist I get this

```
07-Jul-2014 11:30:01 am
```

If I use "UTC" as the time zone

I get it as

```
"2014-07-07 00:00:01 +0000"
```

and inside plist it shows as

```
07-Jul-2014 5:30:01 am
```

I am not understanding what is going on, Can anybody help me out with this

I want to know, if I dont set any timeZone what timeZone will be used?

Do we need to explicitly set UTC as timeZone or we need to use systemTimeZone.

Comment: The time zone you want depends on, err, what time zone you want.  What does the date/time represent?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you question, what info you need?

Comment: What do you mean "save to plist"? How are you saving it?

Comment: I am storing NSdates in a array and storing that array in a plist

Comment: What I mean is the time zone to use will depend on what you want the date/time to represent.  If you wanted a date/time that can be used globally, irrespective of the user's own time zone then you'd want UTC.  If you only care about the local time zone then use that.

Comment: I am creating a Calendar in my app, and user selects any date I am coloring that date. I am used UTC and created my calendar.

Comment: So I just want to make sure that if Im in india and I have selected 7-jul-2014 and colored it on calendar, then if I travel to different time zone then I want 7-jul-2014 to remained colored, is my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to realise about `NSDate` is that there is no such thing as day, week, month, year, timezone, etc...

An `NSDate` is purely a point in time. It has no information about what time zone it is etc...

Effectively it is just a number. You can think of it as using UTC if that helps.

The classes that give you things like time zone are `NSCalendar`, `NSDateFormatter`, etc...

I'm guessing you're in a timezone of UTC+6? Thats why when you create a date with 00:00:01 and you log it out then it displays as 06:00:01.

This is nothing to do with the `NSDate`. What you are seeing in the console is a string. It is a representation of the date object using the default time zone (your own).

I'd have to see you code for saving to a plist but I suspect this is the same problem. You are saving something and assuming it is using a particular time zone when in reality it isn't.

Comment: You also need to mention the classic difference between logging an `NSDate` object using `[NSDate description]` rather than an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Here I created the the date with time 00:00:01, it shows me 6:00:01, but If I create the the date with UTC time zone then why it shows 00:00:01, because UTC time will be 5:30 hrs behind my time zone

Comment: Hello, when we get a date from string whether their is any time associated with it